# Heat map with google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, heatmap

I need to create a heat map with google maps as like in the image,

[image]

I got some details from

https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/1032332?hl=en
But i don't know how to implement it with a website.Is there a js api for this?
Please help to create a heat map for some specific location with custom data.

Comment: I haven't touched Google Maps API for some time, so I can't give you a quick code solution, but hope this can help you: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap

Comment: @MikeNQ The example you have given is working properly